# Java Document data type

Tags: java, variables, casting

I'm trying to use a variable whose value has been set by the user on a form- the value has been read into the variable using the `getDocument()` method provided by swing. The method is in the package: `javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.getDocument()`.

Since I know that the value of the variable holding this information will always be a whole number, I want to use it in another class by passing its value to another variable of type `int`. I'm trying to do this with the following line:

```
public int PORT = Integer.parseInt(variable);
```

However, I'm getting a compile error on `parseInt` that says: "The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Document)".

I understand the reason for this- that I'm getting a variable of data type Document, and trying to move it into a variable of type Int- so the two variables are incompatible data types... I know that you can use `parseInt` to change a String variable to an Int- are there any methods that will allow you to change a Document variable to an Int?

Comment: Use getText() to get the text of the text component as a String. There is no reason to use getDocument(). parseInt() wants a String as argument. You can't pass a Document as argument to parseInt(), since a Document is not a String.

Comment: I am using a class that has been written by someone else as part of a larger program, and didn't really want to change any of the existing code if at all possible... just wanted to know if there was a way of parsing it to an Integer data type. I guess I could just add another variable that would read the same `JTextField`, but store it in a String instead?

Comment: If you only have access to the document, then use [Document.getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#getText%28int,%20int%29). Otherwise, get the text from the text field directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a parameter excetion. Change this

```
public int PORT = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

The parameter must be a String data type object. Otherwise it won't work. This method of parseInt() converts a string to an integer. Document isn't a String that's why it is telling you that there is an exception.

So for this, `getDocument()` would be replaces by `getText()` because you said you only want to get the text. So use this to get the value.

Comment: a String "database"? You mean a String object, or a String instance, right?

Comment: No no, I meant to say Data type object. I mistakenly wrote Database! hehe..@JBNizet :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `javax.swing.text.JTextComponent#getText()` which gives you a `String` that you can parse:

```
int value = defaultValue;
try {
  value = Integer.parseInt(yourTextComponent.getText();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // error during parsing
}
```

If you don't have access to the component but just to it's `Document`, there is a `getText` method as well, use this to convert to `String`, then parse to `int`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I've tried giving it a go- but I get a compile error on the `getText()` method that says: "The method getText(int, int) in the type Document is not applicable for the arguments ()". It recommends that I add arguments to match 'getText(int, int)', which if I do, inserts two 0's into the brackets, i.e. `getText(0, 0)` and my code then compiles... but I'm not sure if that's what I want to be doing?

Comment: @someone2088 You could start by looking into the JavaDoc or online reference of the `Document` class.  You would see that the two arguments of `getText(int, int)` are *offset* and *length*. As you most probably want the full text, *offset* would be `0` and *length* would be the size of the `String`. You can figure out the size of the string with `Document#getLength()`.

Comment: I gave that a go, with the line `public int documentLength = PORT#void getLength(){}`, but I get a syntax error on the # which says "Invalid character, ; expected"... any ideas?

Comment: @someone2088 Yes, that is invalid syntax... Try `public int documentLength = yourDocument.getLength();`. Also, try to use the Java naming convention to name your variables and methods (`PORT` would only be acceptable if that was a constant, i.e. a `final static int` field of your class). In general I would recommend a Java course/tutorial/book so you get to know the basics.